# Como, usando git no Windows, indicar que o arquivo tem permissão de execução em ambientes Unix?

Tags: git, file-permission

Estou usando git no desenvolvimento, e estou querendo colocar o projeto `gradle` para ser executado no CI. Para executar o `gradle`, bastaria dar um `./gradlew` para iniciar o processo. Porém, ao chamar isso no meu CI, ele reclama que o arquivo `gradlew` não é executável.

Porém, não estou conseguindo mudar a permissão deste arquivo, pois todos na equipe usam Windows e `chmod +x` no Windows é no-op, mesmo sobre o git-bash.

Então, como indicar pro git alteração de permissão de execução de um arquivo, através do Windows?

> Não me interessa aqui "corrigir" esse problema a nível de CI, chamando `chmod +x` antes da execução do comando.

Comment: Entendo a necessidade totalmente, eu tenho alguns .sh que passo por isto (gradlew é um), mas será executar `sh ./gradlew` já resolveria?

Comment: Sim, resolveria a "nível de CI", como o `chmod +x`. Mas aqui a intenção é mais geral.

Comment: Estou tão acostumado ao `sh`, que é um comando bem curto, que nem me preocupo muito, mas entendo que na hora de trabalhar em equipe geralmente outros colaboradores beiram muito mais a falta de entendimento minimo, ou até necessidade. Se este for a sua necessidade.

Comment: Chegou a experimentar `git update-index --chmod=+x caminho/gradlew` em Windows?

Comment: Esperava que alguém respondesse isso xD A propósito, funciona (precisou do `--add` quando fui mexer hoje, mas detalhes...)

Comment: É que eu estou sem linux para baixar e testar ver se funcionava, por isso nem respondi, mas que bom que já sabia, agregar conteudo ao site, é o que mais gosto :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para elencar um arquivo com um modo diferente, use o [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index), com a opção [`--chmod=+x`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---chmod-x).

Precisei fazer isso para tornar um script Bash `hbm.sh` executável:

```
$ git update-index --chmod=+x hbm.sh

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   hbm.sh


$ git diff

$ git diff HEAD
diff --git a/hbm.sh b/hbm.sh
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Um detalhe importante de frisar é que a opção de permissões do arquivo precisa estar feita *antes* dos nomes dos arquivos. Então `git update-index arquivo.sh --chmod=+x` não dá o efeito de mudar as permissões do arquivo `arquivo.sh`, mas `git update-index --chmod=+x arquivo.sh` dá o resultado esperado.

Quando precisei fazer isso com o `gradlew`, necessitei adicionar a opção [`--add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---add) na linha de comando:

```
$ git update-index --chmod=+x --add gradlew
```

Isso foi necessário porque o arquivo `gradlew` não estava rastreado, nem mesmo estava elencado/*staged*.

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, graças a isso atualizei 2 projetos para simplificar.