# Listar apenas os arquivos e modos adicionados no elenco do git

Tags: git

Estou tendo problemas para lidar com permissões de arquivos no git. No caso, estou precisando verificar se o arquivo foi adicionado com o modo de permissão correto. Quanto a mudar o modo de permissões, já tem [uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416388/64969). Mas agora preciso confirmar que o arquivo está no modo correto.

Na [citada pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416388/64969), o arquivo já estava adicionado no repositório, então o `git diff` retornava apenas que foi alterada a permissão. Agora, entretanto, o arquivo a ser adicionado precisa entrar em modo específico.

Na hora de validar com `gif diff`, me exibe toda a alteração. Por exemplo:

```
$ git diff HEAD
diff --git a/numobile/android/gradlew b/numobile/android/gradlew
new file mode 100755
index 0000000000..9d82f78915
--- /dev/null
+++ b/numobile/android/gradlew
@@ -0,0 +1,160 @@
+#!/usr/bin/env bash
+
+##############################################################################
+##
+##  Gradle start up script for UN*X
+##
+##############################################################################
+
+# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
+DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""
+
    [ 149 linhas omitidas ... ]
diff --git a/numobile/android/gradlew.bat b/numobile/android/gradlew.bat
new file mode 100644
index 0000000000..aec99730b4
--- /dev/null
+++ b/numobile/android/gradlew.bat
@@ -0,0 +1,90 @@
+@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
+@rem ##########################################################################
+@rem
+@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
+@rem
+@rem ##########################################################################
+
    [ 81 linhas omitidas... ]
```

Atualmente os modos estão corretos, do jeito que eu queria para esses 2 arquivos em particular. Mas eu gostaria de poder listar os arquivos elencados e suas permissões sem precisar navegar por todo o arquivo adicionado.

Por exemplo, mostrando o arquivo e as permissões dele (não precisa ser literalmente assim, é só um exemplo: caminho e permissões):

```
new file numobile/android/gradlew mode 100755 
new file numobile/android/gradlew.bat mode 100644
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é usar `git diff --summary`, pois [segundo a documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---summary), ele mostra apenas algumas informações condensadas, como criação, renomeação e mudanças de modo.

Então ficaria:

```
git diff --summary HEAD
```

Ou, se quiser apenas para alguns arquivos:

```
git diff --summary HEAD -- arquivo1 arquivo2 arquivo3
```

---

Num teste rápido que fiz, alterei o conteúdo (editei e adicionei algumas linhas) e o modo (`git update-index --chmod= etc`) de 2 arquivos.

Usando `git diff HEAD`, ambas as alterações são mostradas:

```
$ git diff HEAD
diff --git a/abc b/abc
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
index 8bea87f..9ae28cc
--- a/abc
+++ b/abc
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-fasd
+fasdfad
+fd
diff --git a/gradlew b/gradlew
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
index 4793523..819f8dc
--- a/gradlew
+++ b/gradlew
@@ -1 +1,5 @@
-fad
+fadffdasfasdfads
+fasdfas
```

Usando a opção `--summary`, são mostradas apenas as alterações de modo, juntamente com o nome do arquivo (abaixo temos os arquivos `abc` e `gradlew`):

```
$ git diff --summary HEAD
 mode change 100644 => 100755 abc
 mode change 100755 => 100644 gradlew
```

E por fim, listando as alterações de apenas de um dos arquivos:

```
$ git diff --summary HEAD -- abc
 mode change 100644 => 100755 abc
```

Comment: Só como observação, descobri que menções ao `HEAD` não funcionam em repositórios sem histórico (obviamente, né?). Então minha alternativa foi concluir o commit para verificar se tinha elencado com a permissão correta e, caso tivesse feito errado, faria `git commit --amend`